# thymeleaf unescaped meta attribute

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

**How can I get an unescaped meta tag attribute value?**

The model attribute (a URL) has its querystring URL encoded, prior to Thymeleaf template processing.

When Thymeleaf processes the template, the Result below has the ampersands HTML encoded to `&amp;`.  They should remain as `&`

**How can I prevent HTML encoding of the meta tag content attribute value?**

Changing the Thymeleaf processing mode to TEXT had no effect.

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=TEXT
```

## Model attribute

```
String absUrl = "http://somewebsite.com/text?phrase=Hit+me+with+the+truth.&author=Billy Someone";
```

## Template

```
<meta property="og:url" th:attr="content=${absUrl}"/>
```

## Result

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://somewebsite.com/text?phrase=Hit+me+with+the+truth.&amp;author=Billy+Someone"/>
```

Comment: The result is correct, why do you want to change it?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, facebook is looking for the canonical URL of page through that og:url meta property.  And if it's to be correct, it should be URLescaped (as in Model), not HTMLescaped as shown in Result.

Comment: Fb or whatever is broken if it can't handle a HTML-escaped attribute value. Have you tested your claim?